# Empty output file generated after running hadoop job

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I have a MapReduce program as below

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.KeyValueTextInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapReduceBase;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.OutputCollector;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Reducer;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Reporter;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextOutputFormat;

public class Sample {

public static class SampleMapper extends MapReduceBase implements
        Mapper<Text, Text, Text, Text> {

    private Text word = new Text();

    @Override
    public void map(Text key, Text value,
            OutputCollector<Text, Text> output, Reporter reporter)
            throws IOException {
        StringTokenizer itr = new StringTokenizer(value.toString(),",");
        while (itr.hasMoreTokens()) {
            word.set(itr.nextToken());
            output.collect(key, word);
        }
    }
}

public static class SampleReducer extends MapReduceBase implements
        Reducer<Text, Text, Text, Text> {

    private Text result = new Text();

    @Override
    public void reduce(Text key, Iterator<Text> values,
            OutputCollector<Text, Text> output, Reporter reporter)
            throws IOException {

        StringBuffer aggregation = new StringBuffer();
        while (values.hasNext()) {
            aggregation.append("|" + values.next().toString());
        }
        result.set(aggregation.toString());
        output.collect(key, result);
    }

}

public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
    JobConf conf = new JobConf(Sample.class);
    conf.setJobName("Sample");

    conf.setMapperClass(SampleMapper.class);
    conf.setReducerClass(SampleReducer.class);
    conf.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    conf.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);
    conf.setInputFormat(KeyValueTextInputFormat.class);
    conf.setOutputFormat(TextOutputFormat.class);
    FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(conf, new Path(args[0]));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(conf, new Path(args[1]));

    JobClient.runJob(conf);

}
}
```

I've made the jar and I've been to trying to get the output. But the output file which is being created is empty.

I'm using the following command to run the job

```
hadoop jar mapreduce.jar Sample /tmp/input tmp/output
```

mapreduce.jar is the jar which I have packaged and my input file is like

```
1 a,b,c
2 e,f
1 x,y,z
2 g
```

expected output

```
1 a|b|c|x|y|z
2 e|f|g
```

Comment: Couple of things: Try setting the number of reducers to 0 and then re-posting the output of the job counters - you should see 4 map input records and 10 map output records. Also, shouldn't you be calling the job.setJarByClass(...) method to configure the job jar?

Comment: Can you also look at the logs to confirm that you're reading from and writing to the directories you think you are?

Comment: Its showing map input records as 4 but the map output records are 0(zero)

Comment: really not able to figure out what the issue is.. Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing that since you're using KeyValueTextInputFormat as the input format that it's not finding a separater byte and is therefore using the entire line value as the key (value is "").  That would mean that your iteration in the mapper doesn't go through any loops and nothing is written out.  Use property name mapreduce.input.keyvaluelinerecordreader.key.value.separator in the config to hold " " as the separator byte.

Comment: The problem was in text input file. Instead of \t after first word. I was using a space. Hate silly mistakes. Neways, thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

Try passing configuration Object to the JobConf , I guess your JobConf is not able to get the Hadoop/hdfs configuration.

```
Configuration configuration=new Configuration();
JobConf jobconf=new JobConf(configuration, exampleClass.class);
conf2.setJarByClass(cls);
.......
```