# Hadoop job not mapping any output when run through terminal but it works fine in eclipse

Tags: java, hadoop

I have a piece of code here.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathConstants;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpression;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataInputStream;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.DataOutputBuffer;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.InputSplit;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.TaskAttemptContext;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.RecordReader;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileSplit;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.TextInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.TextOutputFormat;
import org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.NamedNodeMap;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;


public class XMLParser {    

public static ArrayList<String> a= new ArrayList<>();
public static XPathFactory xpf= XPathFactory.newInstance();
public static javax.xml.xpath.XPath xp= xpf.newXPath();
public static XPathExpression xpe;

/**
 * Reads records that are delimited by a specific begin/end tag.
 */
public static class XmlInputFormat extends TextInputFormat {

    public static final String START_TAG_KEY = "xmlinput.start";
    public static final String END_TAG_KEY = "xmlinput.end";


    public RecordReader<LongWritable, Text> createRecordReader(InputSplit split, TaskAttemptContext context) {
        XmlRecordReader MyXmlReader = new XmlRecordReader();
        try {
            MyXmlReader.initialize(split, context);
        } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return MyXmlReader;
    }

    /**
     * XMLRecordReader class to read through a given xml document to output
     * xml blocks as records as specified by the start tag and end tag
     *
     */

    public static class XmlRecordReader extends RecordReader<LongWritable, Text> {
        private byte[] startTag;
        private byte[] endTag;
        private long start;
        private long end;
        private FSDataInputStream fsin;         
        private DataOutputBuffer buffer = new DataOutputBuffer();
        private int j=0;    //pointer to step back 

        private LongWritable key = new LongWritable();
        private Text value = new Text();
        @Override
        public void initialize(InputSplit split, TaskAttemptContext context)
                throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            Configuration conf = context.getConfiguration();
            startTag = conf.get(START_TAG_KEY).getBytes("utf-8");
            endTag = conf.get(END_TAG_KEY).getBytes("utf-8");
            FileSplit fileSplit = (FileSplit) split;

            // open the file and seek to the start of the split
            start = fileSplit.getStart();
            end = start + fileSplit.getLength();
            Path file = fileSplit.getPath();
            FileSystem fs = file.getFileSystem(conf);
            fsin = fs.open(fileSplit.getPath());
            fsin.seek(start);               

        }
        @Override
        public boolean nextKeyValue() throws IOException,
        InterruptedException {
            if (fsin.getPos() < end) {
                if (readUntilMatch(startTag, false)) {
                    try {
                        fsin.seek(fsin.getPos()-j);
                        if (readUntilMatch(endTag, true)) {
                            key.set(fsin.getPos());
                            value.set(buffer.getData(), 0,
                                    buffer.getLength());
                            return true;
                        }
                    } finally {
                        buffer.reset();
                    }
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
        @Override
        public LongWritable getCurrentKey() throws IOException,
        InterruptedException {
            return key;
        }

        @Override
        public Text getCurrentValue() throws IOException,
        InterruptedException {
            return value;
        }
        @Override
        public void close() throws IOException {
            fsin.close();
        }
        @Override
        public float getProgress() throws IOException {
            return (fsin.getPos() - start) / (float) (end - start);
        }

        private boolean readUntilMatch(byte[] match, boolean withinBlock)
                throws IOException {
            int i = 0;
            while (true) {
                int b = fsin.read();
                // end of file:
                if (b == -1)
                    return false;                   
                // save to buffer:
                if (withinBlock)
                    buffer.write(b);
                // check if we're matching:
                if (b == match[i]) {
                    i++;                        
                    if(i >= match.length){
                        if(!withinBlock) j=i;
                        return true;                        
                    }
                } 
                else if(i>0 && b==0x20){
                    if(!withinBlock) j=i+1; //since the last char wasn't a match, so step back i+1 instead of i chars.
                    return true;
                }
                else i = 0;
                // see if we've passed the stop point:
                if (!withinBlock && i == 0 && fsin.getPos() >= end)
                    return false;
            }
        }
    }
}


public static class Map extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text,Text, Text> { 

    @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
    @Override
    protected void map(LongWritable key, Text value,Mapper.Context context)
            throws
            IOException, InterruptedException {
        String document = value.toString();

        try {                       

            DOMParser parser = new DOMParser();                     

            parser.parse(new InputSource(new java.io.StringReader(document)));
            Document dom = parser.getDocument();

            xpe= xp.compile("//TITLE");
            Node x= (Node) xpe.evaluate(dom, XPathConstants.NODE);

            for(int i=0; i<a.size(); i++){                  
                xpe= xp.compile("//"+a.get(i));
                Node n= (Node) xpe.evaluate(dom, XPathConstants.NODE);
                String a= x.getTextContent();
                String b= i+"\""+traverse(n)+"\"";
                context.write(new Text(a), new Text(b));
            }   


        }
        catch(Exception e){
            throw new IOException(e);
        }
    }

    public static String traverse(Node item) {
        // traversal 
        int x= item.getChildNodes().getLength();
        String s="";
        if(x>1){    //skipping the first #text node
            NodeList l= item.getChildNodes();           
            for(int i=1; i<l.getLength(); i+=2){    //skipping every alternate #text node
                Node n= l.item(i);
                if(i>1)
                    s+="|";
                //if(n.getTextContent().equals("//s+")) continue;
                s+=traverse(n);
            }           
        }

        else{ 
            NamedNodeMap m= item.getAttributes();
            for(int i=0; m!=null && i<m.getLength(); i++){
                if(i>0) s+="|";
                s+= m.item(i).getTextContent().trim();
            }
            s+= item.getTextContent().trim();
        }

        return s;

    }

}

public static class Reduce
extends Reducer<Text, Text, Text, Text> {
    @Override
    protected void setup(Context context)
            throws IOException, InterruptedException {          
        StringBuilder sb= new StringBuilder();
        int i=0;
        for(String s: a){
            if(i>0)
                sb.append(",");
            sb.append(s);
            i++;
        }

        context.write(new Text(sb.toString()), null);

    }
    @Override
    protected void cleanup( Context context)
            throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        context.write(null, null);
    }       

    @Override
    public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<Text> values, Context context)
            throws IOException, InterruptedException {      

        String[] arr= new String[a.size()];
        for(Text value : values){
            String s= value.toString();
            int j= s.indexOf('\"');
            String x= s.substring(0,j);
            int i= Integer.parseInt(x);
            arr[i]= s.substring(j);             
        }

        StringBuilder sb= new StringBuilder();

        for(int i=0; i<arr.length; i++)
            sb.append(arr[i]).append(",");

        context.write(null,new Text(sb.toString()));

    } 
}



@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public static void main(String[] args) throws IllegalArgumentException, IOException, ClassNotFoundException, InterruptedException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
    a.add("TITLE");
    a.add("ARTIST");
    a.add("COUNTRY");
    a.add("PRICE");

    Configuration conf = new Configuration();

    conf.set("xmlinput.start", "<CD>");
    conf.set("xmlinput.end", "</CD>");

    Job job = new Job(conf);
    job.setJarByClass(XMLParser.class);
    job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);
    job.setMapperClass(XMLParser.Map.class);
    job.setReducerClass(XMLParser.Reduce.class);
    job.setInputFormatClass(XmlInputFormat.class);
    job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);
    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
    Path outPath= new Path(args[1]);
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, outPath);
    FileSystem dfs = FileSystem.get(outPath.toUri(), conf);
    if (dfs.exists(outPath)) {
        dfs.delete(outPath, true);
    }
    job.waitForCompletion(true);

}
}
```

The code basically parses any given XML file, and converts it into a csv format. It's written using map-reduce paradigm. In this case, I am inputting a particular xml file that contains something like this:

```
<CATALOG>
<CD>
    <TITLE>Empire Burlesque</TITLE>
    <ARTIST>Bob Dylan</ARTIST>
    <COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY>
    <COMPANY>Columbia</COMPANY>
    <PRICE>10.90</PRICE>
    <YEAR>1985</YEAR>
</CD>
<CD>
    <TITLE>Hide your heart</TITLE>
    <ARTIST>Bonnie Tyler</ARTIST>
    <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>
    <COMPANY>CBS Records</COMPANY>
    <PRICE>9.90</PRICE>
    <YEAR>1988</YEAR>
</CD>
<CD>
    <TITLE>Greatest Hits</TITLE>
    <ARTIST>Dolly Parton</ARTIST>
    <COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY>
    <COMPANY>RCA</COMPANY>
    <PRICE>9.90</PRICE>
    <YEAR>1982</YEAR>
</CD>
<CD>
    <TITLE>Still got the blues</TITLE>
    <ARTIST>Gary Moore</ARTIST>
    <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>
    <COMPANY>Virgin records</COMPANY>
    <PRICE>10.20</PRICE>
    <YEAR>1990</YEAR>
</CD>
<CD>
    <TITLE>Eros</TITLE>
    <ARTIST>Eros Ramazzotti</ARTIST>
    <COUNTRY>EU</COUNTRY>
    <COMPANY>BMG</COMPANY>
    <PRICE>9.90</PRICE>
    <YEAR>1997</YEAR>
</CD>
<CD>
    <TITLE>One night only</TITLE>
    <ARTIST>Bee Gees</ARTIST>
    <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>
    <COMPANY>Polydor</COMPANY>
    <PRICE>10.90</PRICE>
    <YEAR>1998</YEAR>
</CD>
<CD>
    <TITLE>Sylvias Mother</TITLE>
    <ARTIST>Dr.Hook</ARTIST>
    <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>
    <COMPANY>CBS</COMPANY>
    <PRICE>8.10</PRICE>
    <YEAR>1973</YEAR>
</CD>
<CD>
    <TITLE>Maggie May</TITLE>
    <ARTIST>Rod Stewart</ARTIST>
    <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>
    <COMPANY>Pickwick</COMPANY>
    <PRICE>8.50</PRICE>
    <YEAR>1990</YEAR>
</CD>
<CD>
    <TITLE>Romanza</TITLE>
    <ARTIST>Andrea Bocelli</ARTIST>
    <COUNTRY>EU</COUNTRY>
    <COMPANY>Polydor</COMPANY>
    <PRICE>10.80</PRICE>
    <YEAR>1996</YEAR>
</CD>
<CD>
    <TITLE>When a man loves a woman</TITLE>
    <ARTIST>Percy Sledge</ARTIST>
    <COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY>
    <COMPANY>Atlantic</COMPANY>
    <PRICE>8.70</PRICE>
    <YEAR>1987</YEAR>
</CD>
<CD>
    <TITLE>Black angel</TITLE>
    <ARTIST>Savage Rose</ARTIST>
    <COUNTRY>EU</COUNTRY>
    <COMPANY>Mega</COMPANY>
    <PRICE>10.90</PRICE>
    <YEAR>1995</YEAR>
</CD>
<CD>
    <TITLE>1999 Grammy Nominees</TITLE>
    <ARTIST>Many</ARTIST>
    <COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY>
    <COMPANY>Grammy</COMPANY>
    <PRICE>10.20</PRICE>
    <YEAR>1999</YEAR>
</CD>
<CD>
    <TITLE>For the good times</TITLE>
    <ARTIST>Kenny Rogers</ARTIST>
    <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>
    <COMPANY>Mucik Master</COMPANY>
    <PRICE>8.70</PRICE>
    <YEAR>1995</YEAR>
</CD>
<CD>
    <TITLE>Big Willie style</TITLE>
    <ARTIST>Will Smith</ARTIST>
    <COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY>
    <COMPANY>Columbia</COMPANY>
    <PRICE>9.90</PRICE>
    <YEAR>1997</YEAR>
</CD>
<CD>
    <TITLE>Tupelo Honey</TITLE>
    <ARTIST>Van Morrison</ARTIST>
    <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>
    <COMPANY>Polydor</COMPANY>
    <PRICE>8.20</PRICE>
    <YEAR>1971</YEAR>
</CD>
<CD>
    <TITLE>Soulsville</TITLE>
    <ARTIST>Jorn Hoel</ARTIST>
    <COUNTRY>Norway</COUNTRY>
    <COMPANY>WEA</COMPANY>
    <PRICE>7.90</PRICE>
    <YEAR>1996</YEAR>
</CD>
<CD>
    <TITLE>The very best of</TITLE>
    <ARTIST>Cat Stevens</ARTIST>
    <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>
    <COMPANY>Island</COMPANY>
    <PRICE>8.90</PRICE>
    <YEAR>1990</YEAR>
</CD>
<CD>
    <TITLE>Stop</TITLE>
    <ARTIST>Sam Brown</ARTIST>
    <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>
    <COMPANY>A and M</COMPANY>
    <PRICE>8.90</PRICE>
    <YEAR>1988</YEAR>
</CD>
<CD>
    <TITLE>Bridge of Spies</TITLE>
    <ARTIST>T'Pau</ARTIST>
    <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>
    <COMPANY>Siren</COMPANY>
    <PRICE>7.90</PRICE>
    <YEAR>1987</YEAR>
</CD>
<CD>
    <TITLE>Private Dancer</TITLE>
    <ARTIST>Tina Turner</ARTIST>
    <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>
    <COMPANY>Capitol</COMPANY>
    <PRICE>8.90</PRICE>
    <YEAR>1983</YEAR>
</CD>
<CD>
    <TITLE>Midt om natten</TITLE>
    <ARTIST>Kim Larsen</ARTIST>
    <COUNTRY>EU</COUNTRY>
    <COMPANY>Medley</COMPANY>
    <PRICE>7.80</PRICE>
    <YEAR>1983</YEAR>
</CD>
<CD>
    <TITLE>Pavarotti Gala Concert</TITLE>
    <ARTIST>Luciano Pavarotti</ARTIST>
    <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>
    <COMPANY>DECCA</COMPANY>
    <PRICE>9.90</PRICE>
    <YEAR>1991</YEAR>
</CD>
<CD>
    <TITLE>The dock of the bay</TITLE>
    <ARTIST>Otis Redding</ARTIST>
    <COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY>
    <COMPANY>Atlantic</COMPANY>
    <PRICE>7.90</PRICE>
    <YEAR>1987</YEAR>
</CD>
<CD>
    <TITLE>Picture book</TITLE>
    <ARTIST>Simply Red</ARTIST>
    <COUNTRY>EU</COUNTRY>
    <COMPANY>Elektra</COMPANY>
    <PRICE>7.20</PRICE>
    <YEAR>1985</YEAR>
</CD>
<CD>
    <TITLE>Red</TITLE>
    <ARTIST>The Communards</ARTIST>
    <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>
    <COMPANY>London</COMPANY>
    <PRICE>7.80</PRICE>
    <YEAR>1987</YEAR>
</CD>
<CD>
    <TITLE>Unchain my heart</TITLE>
    <ARTIST>Joe Cocker</ARTIST>
    <COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY>
    <COMPANY>EMI</COMPANY>
    <PRICE>8.20</PRICE>
    <YEAR>1987</YEAR>
</CD>
```

When I run it in eclipse,here's the log:

```
File System Counters
    FILE: Number of bytes read=15670
    FILE: Number of bytes written=557909
    FILE: Number of read operations=0
    FILE: Number of large read operations=0
    FILE: Number of write operations=0
Map-Reduce Framework
    Map input records=26
    Map output records=104
    Map output bytes=2760
    Map output materialized bytes=2974
    Input split bytes=120
    Combine input records=0
    Combine output records=0
    Reduce input groups=26
    Reduce shuffle bytes=2974
    Reduce input records=104
    Reduce output records=28
    Spilled Records=208
    Shuffled Maps =1
    Failed Shuffles=0
    Merged Map outputs=1
    GC time elapsed (ms)=122
    CPU time spent (ms)=0
    Physical memory (bytes) snapshot=0
    Virtual memory (bytes) snapshot=0
    Total committed heap usage (bytes)=273162240
Shuffle Errors
    BAD_ID=0
    CONNECTION=0
    IO_ERROR=0
    WRONG_LENGTH=0
    WRONG_MAP=0
    WRONG_REDUCE=0
File Input Format Counters 
    Bytes Read=4669
File Output Format Counters 
    Bytes Written=1193
```

and here's the output:

```
TITLE,ARTIST,COUNTRY,PRICE
"1999 Grammy Nominees","Many","USA","10.20",
"Big Willie style","Will Smith","USA","9.90",
"Black angel","Savage Rose","EU","10.90",
"Bridge of Spies","T'Pau","UK","7.90",
"Empire Burlesque","Bob Dylan","USA","10.90",
"Eros","Eros Ramazzotti","EU","9.90",
"For the good times","Kenny Rogers","UK","8.70",
"Greatest Hits","Dolly Parton","USA","9.90",
"Hide your heart","Bonnie Tyler","UK","9.90",
"Maggie May","Rod Stewart","UK","8.50",
"Midt om natten","Kim Larsen","EU","7.80",
"One night only","Bee Gees","UK","10.90",
"Pavarotti Gala Concert","Luciano Pavarotti","UK","9.90",
"Picture book","Simply Red","EU","7.20",
"Private Dancer","Tina Turner","UK","8.90",
"Red","The Communards","UK","7.80",
"Romanza","Andrea Bocelli","EU","10.80",
"Soulsville","Jorn Hoel","Norway","7.90",
"Still got the blues","Gary Moore","UK","10.20",
"Stop","Sam Brown","UK","8.90",
"Sylvias Mother","Dr.Hook","UK","8.10",
"The dock of the bay","Otis Redding","USA","7.90",
"The very best of","Cat Stevens","UK","8.90",
"Tupelo Honey","Van Morrison","UK","8.20",
"Unchain my heart","Joe Cocker","USA","8.20",
"When a man loves a woman","Percy Sledge","USA","8.70",
```

As you can see, everything is fine here. I also see the desired result in the output folder. Here's the catch though: when I run it on the terminal using the following command that uses the jar file:

```
hadoop jar ./jobs/xmlParser.jar XMLParser cd.xml output
```

I get the following result:

```
File System Counters
    FILE: Number of bytes read=6
    FILE: Number of bytes written=212423
    FILE: Number of read operations=0
    FILE: Number of large read operations=0
    FILE: Number of write operations=0
    HDFS: Number of bytes read=4881
    HDFS: Number of bytes written=1
    HDFS: Number of read operations=7
    HDFS: Number of large read operations=0
    HDFS: Number of write operations=2
Job Counters 
    Launched map tasks=1
    Launched reduce tasks=1
    Data-local map tasks=1
    Total time spent by all maps in occupied slots (ms)=6709
    Total time spent by all reduces in occupied slots (ms)=7079
    Total time spent by all map tasks (ms)=6709
    Total time spent by all reduce tasks (ms)=7079
    Total vcore-seconds taken by all map tasks=6709
    Total vcore-seconds taken by all reduce tasks=7079
    Total megabyte-seconds taken by all map tasks=6870016
    Total megabyte-seconds taken by all reduce tasks=7248896
Map-Reduce Framework
    Map input records=26
    Map output records=0
    Map output bytes=0
    Map output materialized bytes=6
    Input split bytes=108
    Combine input records=0
    Combine output records=0
    Reduce input groups=0
    Reduce shuffle bytes=6
    Reduce input records=0
    Reduce output records=2
    Spilled Records=0
    Shuffled Maps =1
    Failed Shuffles=0
    Merged Map outputs=1
    GC time elapsed (ms)=167
    CPU time spent (ms)=2250
    Physical memory (bytes) snapshot=329895936
    Virtual memory (bytes) snapshot=1601593344
    Total committed heap usage (bytes)=168235008
Shuffle Errors
    BAD_ID=0
    CONNECTION=0
    IO_ERROR=0
    WRONG_LENGTH=0
    WRONG_MAP=0
    WRONG_REDUCE=0
File Input Format Counters 
    Bytes Read=4773
File Output Format Counters 
    Bytes Written=1
```

And when I check the output, I see an empty text file.
I also followed the steps mentioned by @Chris Gerkin on this page:
[Empty output file generated after running hadoop job](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12780407/empty-output-file-generated-after-running-hadoop-job). But it didn't work.
Can anyone please help me resolve this problem? Thanks.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could also add what command is used to run the mapreduce job from terminal.

Comment: I have added the command now. Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eureka! I found the error. Turns out the problem was with the global static ArrayList a that I was using. In the pseudo-distributed/ distributed mode, that global variable won't be visible to the datanodes doing the mapping/reducing job. That's why it won't output anything.